# Call another controller function based on drop down selection

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, anchor

I'm building a site that hosts stories that have multiple chapters and on my view I would like the user to be able to select from a drop down menu and go to the chapter they have selected.

I have the drop down populating with information from the database, I'm just having trouble calling another controller based on that selection.

In my view this is my drop down

```
<select>
 <?foreach($chapter as $row) :?>
   <option value="<?=$row->chapter_title?>"><?=$row->chapter_title?></option>
 <?endforeach;?>
</select>
```

I did try and add a link to the controller in the option, but that didn't work.

```
<select>
 <?foreach($chapter as $row) :?>
  <option value="<?=$row->chapter_title?>">
     <?=anchor('story/viewChapter/'.$row->chapter_id, $row->chapter_title);?>
  </option>
 <?endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Is there any other way I can do this that does not involve javascript?

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript?

Comment: I'm trying to make the site not dependent of javascript, because some of my target market can't have javascript enabled.

Comment: Interesting, the only other option would be to wrap everything in a form and place a submit button next to the select. Then do the redirect in the php code depending on the value of the postdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will have to use javascript:

If your using jquery you could try something like this:

```
$('#select_id').change(function(){
  var chapter = $(this).val();
  $(location).attr('href','http://www.mysite.com/books?chapter='+chapter);
});
```

Here is an example:

http://jsbin.com/efidar/1/